# Should mongodb insert data ordered according with their indexes?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know if mongodb should re-order data after insert data according with the indexes configured previously, for instance:

After insert data according with sequence bellow:

```
db.test.insert(_id:1)
db.test.insert(_id:5)
db.test.insert(_id:2)
```

And executing the following search:

```
db.test.find();
```

We can see the result:

```
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 3 }
```

As we know, the field _id by default has a index, the question here is why after executing search the results are not return in sequence as presented bellow?

```
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB indexes are separate data structures that contain the portion of the collection being indexed. The index does not dictate the order of documents in storage during insert.

Indexes are only used for sorting when a sort order is specified in the search:

```
db.test.find().sort({ _id: 1 })
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 5 }
```

You can verify the index usage using explain:

```
db.test.explain().find().sort({_id:1})
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "so.test",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [ ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "_id" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "_id_",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "_id" : [
                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "KSA303096TX2",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.11",
                "gitVersion" : "48f8b49dc30cc2485c6c1f3db31b723258fcbf39 modules: enterprise"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I did this question because I have a collection with 5GB of data and when I try to use sort command the database ranges because all memory availabe was consumed and there is no more available to perform sort.